# Как найти в строке построку с расширением средствами java script

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть file.txt
со следующим содержанием

```
/foo00/bar00/baz00.txt
/foo01/bar01/baz01.txt
/foo02/bar02/baz02.txt
```

Как мне записать регулярное выражение для того что бы находить название файла `baz00.txt, baz01.txt, baz02.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо так... 

`\d` от слова digit - цифра. Символ `+` означат "одно или несколько совпадений". А точка `.` в регулярках совпадает со всем подряд... поэтому она отже отключается через обратный слэш `\.`

```js
let str0 = '/foo00/bar00/baz00.txt';
let str1 = '/foo01/bar01/baz01.txt';
let str2 = '/foo02/bar02/baz02.txt';

console.log( str0.match(/baz\d+\.txt/)[0] );
console.log( (/baz\d+\.txt/).exec(str0)[0] );

console.log( str1.match(/baz\d+\.txt/)[0] );
console.log( (/baz\d+\.txt/).exec(str1)[0] );

console.log( str2.match(/baz\d+\.txt/)[0] );
console.log( (/baz\d+\.txt/).exec(str2)[0] );
```

P.s. https://regex101.com/r/86z7U0/1 - здесь нагляднее.